# How to debug why Chrome browser on Mac giving JPEGs a red hue?

Tags: google-chrome, jpeg, color-profiles

I'm having a strange issue on my Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.6 when using Chrome Version 60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit).  I don't see it in Safari, nor in Photoshop CS6.  All JPEG files have an artificial red hue added to them but PNGs are not affected, see this side-by-side example:

[image]

And here is the same thing in Safari rendered properly:

[image]

Where might this be coming from and how would I best go about tracking the cause down?

Comment: [Just a guess] Check the picture colour profile - at a guess, it's not sRGB. Safari will repro other profiles, some browsers will not & will just assume sRGB. ProPhoto might produce that red shift.